# For $m \in \text{max} \ R[X]$ and $f \in R[X] \setminus m, \ R[X]_f$ is not a local ring

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, commutative-algebra, maximal-and-prime-ideals, localization

> Let $R$ be a commutative ring with $1$ and $m$ be a maximal ideal of $R[X]$. Let $f \in R[X]$ such that $f \notin m$. Then I want to show that $R[X]_f$ is not a local ring, where $R[X]_f$ is the localization of $R[X]$ with respect to the multiplicative closed set $\{ 1 , f ,f ^{2}, \ldots \}$.

**My effort:** On the contrary if we assume that $R[X]_f$ is local then clearly $R[X]_f \cong R[X]_{m}.$

But then I couldn't draw any contradiction. Please don't give me a reference where it was proved that there is another maximal ideal $n$ of $R[X]$ different from $m$ such that $f \notin n$ as well. To be honest I want to prove the previously stated fact in a different way.

Comment: I can't see any reason to prove this result "in a different way". Showing that there is a maximal ideal of $R[X]$ not containing $f$ and different from $M$ is the natural approach, and its proof isn't quite trivial.

Answer (score 0):

We refer to the following commutative diagram:

[image: Diagram]

Let $\text{loc}_f:R[X]\to R[X]_f$ be the canonical localization and $\eta:R[X]\to R[X]/m$ be the canonical quotient. Note that $R[X]/m$ is a field with $\eta(f)\neq 0$ and thus by the universal property of localization that there exists a unique ring morphism $k:R[X]_f\to R[X]/m$ with $\eta=k\circ \text{loc}$. Clearly $\text{ker}(k)\subsetneq R[X]_f$ is maximal.

Now denote by $\pi:R[X]\to R[X]$ the unique automorphism fixing $R\subset R[X]$ and taking $x\mapsto x+1$ and by $\pi^{-1}$ its inverse. From the U.P. of localization this induces an automorphism $\text{loc}(\pi):R[X]_f\to R[X]_f$ such that the "obvious" square $\text{loc}_f\circ \pi= \text{loc}(\pi)\circ \text{loc}_f$ commutes.

Observe that $\text{ker}(k\circ \text{loc}(\pi)^{-1})\subsetneq R[X]_f$ is like $\text{ker}(k)$ maximal. But $$k\circ\text{loc}_f=\eta=k\circ \text{loc}(\pi)^{-1}\circ \text{loc}_f\circ \pi$$ From which it follows that $$\text{loc}_f(p)\in \text{ker}(k)\iff p\in \text{ker}(\eta)\iff \text{loc}_f(p+1)\in \text{ker}(k\circ \text{loc}(\pi)^{-1})$$ And thus that $\text{ker}(k)$ and $\text{ker}(k\circ \text{loc}(\pi)^{-1})$ are disjoint maximal ideals of $R[X]_f$, as desired $\blacksquare$

Comment: I think it's no a good idea to denote with $f$ the ring homomorphism $R[X]_f\to R[X]/m$... Moreover, what's $f'$?

Comment: Typos corrected. Hopefully the diagram makes the argument a bit clearer :)

Comment: The right-hand square in your diagram is not necessarily commutative.

Comment: $\text{quot}(\text{loc}(\pi))$ is defined to be the unique map for which $\text{quot}(\text{loc}(\pi))\circ f=f\circ \text{loc}(\pi)$ by the universal property of the quotient.

Comment: This map there exists provided that $\pi[m]=m$.

Comment: You are right, hopefully it is fixed now. (Tangentially I now realize that I have labeled by $f$ a ring morphism unrelated to the original post's $f$. It shouldn't affect the proof, but oops.)

Answer (score -2):

We have $R[X]_{m} /(m\cdot R[X]_m)$ is a field. Whereas, 
$B = (R[x]_f)/(m \cdot R[x]_f) = (R/m) [X]_f$ is not a field as the image $\bar{f}$, of $f$ in $(R/m) [X]$ which is a principal ideal domain with infinitely many prime ideals, has only finitely many prime
divisors and all the prime ideal to which $\bar{f}$ does not belong survive in $B$.

Comment: Something is wrong. $mR[X]_f$ is indeed a maximal ideal of $R[X]_f.$